# Не работает JS при использовании Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot

Проблема в том, что скрипт не подключается к мой странице html. 
Использую Spring boot 1.5.10

Окно проекта:

[image: Окно проекта]

Содержимое index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>

<body>
<p>Начало документа</p>

<p>Конец документа</p>

</body>
<script src="../public/js/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Пробовал заменить **src="../public/js/index.js"** на **th:src="@{../public/js/index.js}**, но все равно скрипт не выполняется.

index.js содержит `alert ('JS подключен и отлично работает!');`

Браузер жалуется на `GET http://localhost:8080/public/script.js net::ERR_ABORTED`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал закинуть файл `script.js` в папку `templates`, указать `src="script.js"` или `src="/script.js"`, но все равно ошибка одна и та же.

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Не обращайте внимание на то, что скрипт в одном месте называется "script.js", а в другом "index.js", а так же путь к файлу. Скриншоты и код были сделаны в разное время. На самом деле там названия одинаковые. Уже замучился тестировать, кидал во все папки.

Comment: Может я чего-то не понимаю, но пути `/public/js/script.js` у вас нет. Зато есть путь `/public.js/script.js`

Comment: в файловой структуре /public.js/script.js =  /public/js/script.js. Idea так именует папки, внутри которой одна папка

Comment: А вы посмотрите каталог out - там по идеи должны лежать скомпилированные файлы. И вы увидите, по какомум пути там лежат скрипты.

Comment: а положить *.js  в папку js что около html лежит нельзя?